# How to do a conditional NA fill in R dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse, na

It may be simple but could not figure out.
How to fill `NA` in the `feature` column with conditions as below in the data frame `dt`.

The conditions to fill NA are:

1. if the difference in Date is `1`, fill the `NA` with the previous row's value (easily done by fill function of tidyverse)

```
dt_fl<-dt%>%
  fill(feature, .direction = "down")
dt_fl
```

2. if the difference in the Date is `>1`, then fill the `NA` with the previous feature value +1 and replace the following rows (feature values) with `1` increment to make continuous feature values.
   The `dt_output` shows what I am expecting from `dt` after filling `NA` values and replacing the feature numbers accordingly.

```
dt<-structure(list(Date = structure(c(15126, 15127, 15128, 15129, 
                    15130, 15131, 15132, 15133, 15134, 15138, 15139, 15140, 15141, 
                    15142, 15143, 15144, 15145, 15146, 15147, 15148, 15149), class = "Date"), 
                    feature = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -21L), class = c("tbl_df", 
                    "tbl", "data.frame"))
 dt

dt_output<-structure(list(Date = structure(c(15126, 15127, 15128, 15129, 
          15130, 15131, 15132, 15133, 15134, 15138, 15139, 15140, 15141, 
          15142, 15143, 15144, 15145, 15146, 15147, 15148, 15149), class = "Date"), 
          feature = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
          2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, NA), finaloutput = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
          1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3)), row.names = c(NA, 
           -21L), spec = structure(list(cols = list(Date = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
          "collector")), feature = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
            "collector")), finaloutput = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
          "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
          "collector")), skip = 1L), class = "col_spec"), class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
          "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
dt_output
```

Also, following Ben's suggestion, if the data frame starts with `NA` feature like in `dt2` how to fix it? Expected output for `dt2` is in `dt2_output`

```
  dt2<-structure(list(Date = structure(c(13675, 13676, 13677, 13678, 
      13679, 13689, 13690, 13691, 13692, 13693, 13694, 13695), class = "Date"), 
    feature = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, NA, 2)), row.names = c(NA, 
    -12L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

```
dt2_output<-structure(list(Date = structure(c(13675, 13676, 13677, 13678, 
              13679, 13689, 13690, 13691, 13692, 13693, 13694, 13695), class = "Date"), 
              feature = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, NA, 2), output_feature = c(1, 
              1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3)), row.names = c(NA, -12L
              ), spec = structure(list(cols = list(Date = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
              "collector")), feature = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
              "collector")), output_feature = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
              "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
              "collector")), skip = 1L), class = "col_spec"), class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
              "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

The solution Ben provides works fine for all the conditions except in 1 condition like in `dt3` (below), just wondering why it is so. My assumption is the second solution should give `dt3_expected` for `dt3`.

```
dt3<-structure(list(Date = structure(c(10063, 10064, 10065, 10066, 
     10067, 10068, 10069, 10070, 10079, 10080, 10081, 10082, 10083, 
     10084, 10085, 10086, 10087, 10088, 10089), class = "Date"), feature = c(1, 
     1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, NA, NA, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
    -19L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

dt3
```

```
dt3_expected<-structure(list(Date = structure(c(10063, 10064, 10065, 10066, 
10067, 10068, 10069, 10070, 10079, 10080, 10081, 10082, 10083, 
10084, 10085, 10086, 10087, 10088, 10089), class = "Date"), feature = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, NA, NA, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, NA), output_feature = c(1, 
 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)), row.names = c(NA, 
-19L), spec = structure(list(cols = list(Date = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
 "collector")), feature = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), output_feature = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
  "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
  "collector")), skip = 1L), class = "col_spec"), class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
  "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

The help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: The expected output for dt2 is also added.

Comment: Thank you - please see edited answer and let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Awesome solution Ben, however, it is not happy in one of the condition, I could not figure out why. I have modified the question for 3rd conditions where the output is different than what I was expecting.

Comment: I think I may be a bit confused on the logic for determining the `feature` value. In the first `dt`, there was `NA` on 6/17/11 which became 2, and then 2 on 6/18/11 which became 3 (even though there was no date difference). However, in `dt3`, there is `NA` on 8/6/97 which shares the same `output_feature` of 2 as 8/7/97. Why is `output_feature` the same 8/6/97 and 8/7/97 in `dt3` but not the same in `dt` for 6/17/11 and 6/18/11?

Comment: These are spatial features  so  dates gap would not work. Every feature should is >=5 days. In the dt there are >5 NA but in ```dt3``` it is only 1 NA after filling the first value, so it is part of the following feature. So the conditions are: (I)if the difference in Date is 1, fill the NA with the previous row's value (ii)if the difference in Date is >1 and there are only  2NA, fill first NA by last previous feature and second by first the following feature 
 and (iii) if the difference in the Date is >1, and there are more than 2 NA then fill the NA with the previous feature value +1

Comment: Please see edited answer. This could be simplified, but first would like to see that this works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try creating an "offset" that is added whenever you have missing values and a difference in dates greater than 1 day. This cumulative offset can be added to your `feature` value to determine the `finaloutput`.

```
dt %>%
  mutate(offset = cumsum(is.na(feature) & Date - lag(Date) > 1)) %>%
  fill(feature, .direction = "down") %>%
  mutate(finaloutput = feature + offset)
```

**Output**

```
# A tibble: 21 x 4
   Date       feature offset finaloutput
   <date>       <dbl>  <int>       <dbl>
 1 2011-06-01       1      0           1
 2 2011-06-02       1      0           1
 3 2011-06-03       1      0           1
 4 2011-06-04       1      0           1
 5 2011-06-05       1      0           1
 6 2011-06-06       1      0           1
 7 2011-06-07       1      0           1
 8 2011-06-08       1      0           1
 9 2011-06-09       1      0           1
10 2011-06-13       1      1           2
11 2011-06-14       1      1           2
12 2011-06-15       1      1           2
13 2011-06-16       1      1           2
14 2011-06-17       1      1           2
15 2011-06-18       2      1           3
16 2011-06-19       2      1           3
17 2011-06-20       2      1           3
18 2011-06-21       2      1           3
19 2011-06-22       2      1           3
20 2011-06-23       2      1           3
21 2011-06-24       2      1           3
```

**Edit**: With the second example `dt2` that begins with `NA`, you can try the following.

First, you can add a `default` for `lag`. In the case where the first row is `NA`, it will evaluate for a difference in `Date`. Since there is no prior `Date` to compare with, you can use a default of more than 1 day, so that an offset will be added and these initial `NA` will be considered the "first" `feature`.

The second issue is filling in the `NA` when you can't `fill` in the down direction (no prior `feature` value when it starts with `NA`). You can just replace these with 0. Given the `offset`, this will become `finaloutput` of 0 + 1 = 1.

```
dt2 %>%
  mutate(offset = cumsum(is.na(feature) & Date - lag(Date, default = first(Date) - 2) > 1)) %>%
  fill(feature, .direction = "down") %>%
  replace_na(list(feature = 0)) %>%
  mutate(finaloutput = feature + offset)
```

**Output**

```
   Date       feature offset finaloutput
   <date>       <dbl>  <int>       <dbl>
 1 2007-06-11       0      1           1
 2 2007-06-12       0      1           1
 3 2007-06-13       0      1           1
 4 2007-06-14       0      1           1
 5 2007-06-15       0      1           1
 6 2007-06-25       1      1           2
 7 2007-06-26       1      1           2
 8 2007-06-27       1      1           2
 9 2007-06-28       1      1           2
10 2007-06-29       1      1           2
11 2007-06-30       1      1           2
12 2007-07-01       2      1           3
```

**Edit**: With additional comment, there is an additional criterion to consider.

If the difference in `Date` is > 1 and there are only 2 `NA`, the first `NA` should be filled by the previous feature, and the second by the following feature. In particular, the second of 2 `NA` where there is a gap should be dealt with differently.

One approach to this is to count the number of consecutive `NA` in a row. Then, `feature` can be filled in for this particular circumstance, where the second of two `NA` is identified with a `Date` gap.

```
dt3 %>%
  mutate(grp = cumsum(c(1, abs(diff(is.na(feature))) == 1))) %>%
  add_count(grp) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  mutate(feature = ifelse(is.na(feature) & n == 2 & is.na(lag(feature)), lead(feature), feature)) %>%
  mutate(offset = cumsum(is.na(feature) & Date - lag(Date, default = first(Date) - 2) > 1)) %>%
  fill(feature, .direction = "down") %>%
  replace_na(list(feature = 0)) %>%
  mutate(finaloutput = feature + offset)
```

**Output**

```
   Date       feature   grp     n offset finaloutput
   <date>       <dbl> <dbl> <int>  <int>       <dbl>
 1 1997-07-21       1     1     7      0           1
 2 1997-07-22       1     1     7      0           1
 3 1997-07-23       1     1     7      0           1
 4 1997-07-24       1     1     7      0           1
 5 1997-07-25       1     1     7      0           1
 6 1997-07-26       1     1     7      0           1
 7 1997-07-27       1     1     7      0           1
 8 1997-07-28       1     2     2      0           1
 9 1997-08-06       2     2     2      0           2
10 1997-08-07       2     3     9      0           2
11 1997-08-08       2     3     9      0           2
12 1997-08-09       2     3     9      0           2
13 1997-08-10       2     3     9      0           2
14 1997-08-11       2     3     9      0           2
15 1997-08-12       2     3     9      0           2
16 1997-08-13       2     3     9      0           2
17 1997-08-14       2     3     9      0           2
18 1997-08-15       2     3     9      0           2
19 1997-08-16       2     4     1      0           2
```

Note that this could be simplified; but before doing so, will need to be sure this meets your needs.

Comment: Can you edit your question with an example with features that start with `NA` - as well as what the desired result should look like in that case?